# How do I find the last level cache size of an ARM processor on runtime?

Tags: c++, caching, arm

I'm currently writing a custom DNN kernel to run on ARM-based devices. (Using C++, with GCC 7.5.0)

My code slices the given workload into batches that would fit in the last level cache, in an effort to reduce main memory accesses.

I've successfully implemented the code to work on my development board with the given cache size from the manufacturer, but the binary is expected to run on multiple environments, each possibly with different cache configurations.

Is there a way for my program to know the last level cache information of the given system on runtime? Maybe a system call?

The expected environment is ARMv8-A (on aarch64 mode), probably with Linux Kernel 4.3 and up.

I have tried /proc/cpuinfo , getconf , cpuid , lscpu , lshw , and although these work fine on my x86 based desktop, none of these return any info about cache sizes on my development board. (Odroid N2+, Ubuntu 18.04, Linux 4.9.230).

Comment: You should look at the ARM reference manual for your processor to find the instruction(s) for reading the cache size (if there is an instruction).  Also, search the internet for ARM cache sizes.  My understanding is that the cache sizes are fixed and cannot change during runtime.

Comment: The linux information commands may be table lookup.  They mysteriously get the platform name, then look up the information in a table.  There is no guarantee that the platform has functionality to return all the information and there are no requirements to do so.

Comment: I might just find the cache data of all possible devices that I expect and store that in the code somewhere, as a lookup table. Although that would mean that it would fall back to a default value (prob. 512kb) if it's ran on a unknown device, which wouldn't be optimal. But still, thank you for your suggestion.